# Webpack vendors JS bundle (Vue CLI) includes code not listed in dependencies or package-lock.json?

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, package.json, vue-cli

Information security auditing tool raised a flag for an outdated library with known vulnerabilities found in our webpack-bundled (by Vue CLI) `chunk-vendors.js` file:

YUI 2.9.0

It seems this library is not even included in its entirety, as it is only this short snippet code:

`/*! Copyright (c) 2011, Yahoo! Inc. All rights reserved. Code licensed under the BSD License: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/license.html version: 2.9.0 */if(void 0===a)var a={};a.lang={extend:function(e,n,i){if(!n||!e)throw new Error("YAHOO.lang.extend failed, please check that all dependencies are included.");var a=function(){};if(a.prototype=n.prototype,e.prototype=new a,e.prototype.constructor=e,e.superclass=n.prototype,n.prototype.constructor==Object.prototype.constructor&&(n.prototype.constructor=n),i){var o;for(o in i)e.prototype[o]=i[o];var s=function(){},c=["toString","valueOf"];try{/MSIE/.test(r.userAgent)&&(s=function(t,e){for(o=0;o<c.length;o+=1){var n=c[o],r=e[n];"function"==typeof r&&r!=Object.prototype[n]&&(t[n]=r)}})}catch(t){}s(e.prototype,i)}}};`

I was expecting to find YUI dependency installed by NPM and thus found in `package-lock.json`, however, there is no `yui` found in the lock file.

**How can this dependency be included `chunk-vendors.js` file while not being included in `package-lock.json`, or how to debug this?**

Comment: Just do a simple file grep through `node_modules` looking for the above copyright text

Comment: @IVOGELOV thank you, this helped! As I'm in on a Windows machine, executing this command in `node_modules` folder pinpointed the dependency files related to this: `findstr /s /i /m \<developer.yahoo.com\> *.* > results.out` - please make an answer so I will mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to find the guilty dependency you may simply perform a grep search through the `node_modules` looking for the copyright text mentioned above.
For Windows you can use PowerGREP or the CLI command `findstr /s /i /m \<developer.yahoo.com\> *.* > results.out` (`s` for recursive search, `i` for case-insensitive search, `m` to print just the filename instead of the exact line with the match)